# Can I change contents of UIView dynamically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I Want to change contents of UIView dynamically without using removeFromSuperView and addSubview.the codes is an image of what I want to do.

```
int screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
int screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height;
UIView *currentView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight)];
UIView *nextView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight)];

[self.view addSubview:currentView];

currentView = nextView;

//when this code run,appearing currentView swap nextView.
[self.view reload];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely. If you want it to look nice, create the "end" view with the attributes you want and use a static [transition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW113) method: `+transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:`.

This will remove and add views, as needed, so that you don't have to call those methods. Otherwise, you can use the `-setHidden:` method suggested by *janusfidel*, in order to hide the view you don't want to see.

Answer (score 0):

```
//in viewdidload
{
........
........
[self.view addSubview:currentView];
[self.view addSubview:nextView];
nextView .hidden = YES;
}

-(void)changeView
{
if(!currentView .hidden)
{
currentView .hidden =YES;
nextView .hidden = NO;
}
else
{
currentView .hidden =NO;
nextView .hidden = YES;
}
}
```